# Cross Domain Post to Sinatra

Tags: html, cross-domain, sinatra

Hi I have a static website hosted on AWS S3 and I would like to be able to send emails from the "Contact Us form on the page". Is it possible to have a Sinatra server running on a different domain, lets say Heroku that would handle the POST and send an email.

I have the email portion from Sinatra working but every time I POST on my local I get

```
WARN -- : attack prevented by Rack::Protection::HttpOrigin
```

My form is this `<form action="http://localhost:4567/contact" method="post">`.

If I understand correctly this should work because I am not using JavaScript, but I am not sure.

Also, is it possible to have my static site auto redirect me to the index page or do I need to do that from Sinatra?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can, by specifying an *origin whitelist* in Sinatra's options:

```ruby
configure do
  set :protection, :origin_whitelist => ['http://example.com']
end
```

Replace `http://example.com` with the URL where you're sending the POST request from.

Comment: Thanks, Im knew to Sinatra and I should have figured to look for something like that first.